# Type safe way to handle subset of enum differently

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum and a type that is representing a subset of that enum. I need to handle values in that subset differently than other values. Right now I use a `if` with multiple conditions, but it might become very large if there are many values in the type.

```
enum Country {
    Canada,
    Finland,
    France,
    Germany,
    Japan,
    Peru,
}

type EuropeanCountries = Country.Finland | Country.France | Country.Germany;

const NonEuropeanCountriesContinent: Record<
    Exclude<Country, EuropeanCountries>,
    string
> = {
    [Country.Canada]: "America",
    [Country.Japan]: "Asia",
    [Country.Peru]: "America",
}

function getContinent(country: Country) {
    // Here I would like to not have to manually check each value
    if (country === Country.France || country === Country.Finland || country === Country.Germany) {
        return "Europe";
    }

    return NonEuropeanCountriesContinent[country];
}
```

How can I check if my `country` variable's value is inside `EuropeanCountries` without having to manually go through each value of `EuropeanCountries`?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9mEAXATgTygbwFBT7AQxAIBMCAaXfAMQEsQAbIky-KalIgY2FfwHFgKCETR88AKQIAHIuKgAFIWEoBfbNiRppwKAFEwKODqLxEqWsADOUALywEydADo6jZlAA+D8y47ddbzMnNGdBYVEAbg0uOBArJCgAOTiDIxMQYItreGR6UCQALigAJWBYlBIAHio8PQAPLgYwEmAqrPRyfUNjYFNHbKsAPnkElHoAc2whuyxaqABtDtCYIlICAF1igCIAQQghWi4CbfklgZcpWRAtqD2rWhOz5eclFDBbvYPx49PsdWwADNEFwkLQ4lAJsAkLkwSACgAKWK+NDFZYASjmbFogKgSIuGFsRJ8IVcnBAPC83mRITsxJebiYIBIVKgNNQhPpBLCQhEIDQmJwbDYKGhhhAdzSvW20TYAJFYpQEpSIClGQ6lissPyyAW7PQG2iqiAA)

Comment: Typescript types are erased during transpilation, so you cannot check if an object is an instance of a certain type at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to maintain that record of which enum values belongs to EU, and which do not, then you can use a Custom Type Guard to check type like this:

```
enum Country {
    Canada,
    Finland,
    France,
    Germany,
    Japan,
    Peru,
}

type EuropeanCountries = Country.Finland | Country.France | Country.Germany;
const EuropeContinent: Record<EuropeanCountries, string> = {
    [Country.Finland]: "Europe",
    [Country.France]: "Europe",
    [Country.Germany]: "Europe",
}
const NonEuropeanCountriesContinent: Record<
    Exclude<Country, EuropeanCountries>,
    string
> = {
    [Country.Canada]: "America",
    [Country.Japan]: "Asia",
    [Country.Peru]: "America",
}

function getContinent(country: Country) {
    if(isInEurope(country)) {
        return EuropeContinent[country];
    }

    return NonEuropeanCountriesContinent[country];
}

function isInEurope(country: EuropeanCountries | Exclude<Country, EuropeanCountries>): country is EuropeanCountries {
    return !!EuropeContinent[country as EuropeanCountries];
}

console.log(getContinent(Country.Finland));
console.log(getContinent(Country.Peru));
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with something similar. The `isInEurope` function is what is was looking for.